# Why is this question worded like this regarding main memory?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have this question:

***1. How many bits are required to address a 4M × 16 main memory if main memory is word-addressable?***

And before you say it, yes I have looked this question up and there have been posts on stackoverflow asking about how to answer it but my question is different.

This may sound like a silly question but I don't understand what it means when it says **"How many bits are required to address..."**.

To my understanding and what I have been taught is that (if we're talking about word addressable) each cell would contain 16 bits in the RAM chip and the length would be 4M-1, with 2^22 words. But I don't understand what it is asking when it says 'How many bits are required...':

The answer says 22 bits would be required but I just don't understand. 22 bits for what? All I know is each word is 16 bits and each cell would be numbered from 0 - 4M-1. Can someone clear this up for me please?

Comment: Each cell needs to have a distinct address. How many addresses do you need? How many bits do you need to be able to represent all these addresses? Other way of looking at it: how wide does the address bus need to be if you want to be able to access each cell individually?

Comment: It is 16, you need 4M addresses numbered 0 - 4M-1. To represent all these addresses you need 16 bits as each word is 16 bits. it literally says in the question 4M × 16, so where is 22 coming from? @Mat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many bits' address is required for a computer with n bytes of memory?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/178921/30872)

Comment: it says 4M × 16 in the question, which means each cell has 16 bits = 1 word @Mat

Comment: `It is 16, you need 4M addresses numbered 0 - 4M-1` - correct. `To represent all these addresses you need 16 bits as each word is 16 bits` - incorrect.

Comment: The CPU has to have enough address lines to send over every possible address.  In this case, the CPU would need 22 address lines to do that.

Comment: I am so confused, do you need 22 address lines or 4,194,304 address lines? @TimRoberts

Comment: what is the difference between needing 22 bits and each word is 16 bits in a cell? @GSerg

Comment: The difference is that "22 bits" is the correct answer to the question posed, and "16 bits in a cell" is irrelevant information. I have to conclude that you are trolling at this point. If somehow you aren't, and genuinely have no clue what the [binary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) is, then familiarize yourself with that a little bit, then practice to solve problems such as "how many bits are needed to represent number 15231 in binary", irrespective to computers and their memory architecture. You are being asked "how many bits needed to represent number 4194303".

Comment: Think about it this way.  3 bits lets you refer to 8 addresses: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111.  Similarly 22 bits lets you refer to 4M addresses.

Comment: okay what is the size of each cell in byte addressable memory if the question doesn't specify? @TimRoberts

Comment: You said it: in "byte addressable" memory, every cell is an 8-bit byte.  The question stated "word addressable", where every cell is 16 bits.  Today, almost everything is byte-addressable, but the early mainframe days had a wide variety.  The CDC mainframes used 60-bit words, so each cell was 60 bits.

Comment: what I mean is, every cell is an 8-bit byte yes but how long is each word, as in, how many 8-bit bytes make up a row if question doesn't specify? @TimRoberts

Comment: The words "row" has no meaning in this discussion.  Say you have a memory of 64 bits.  If that memory is byte-addressable, then you have a total of 8 bytes, and you need 3 address bits to access them.  If that memory is word-addressable, then you have a total of 4 words, and you need 2 address bits to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have 4 million cells, you need a number that is able to represent each cell. 22 bits is the size of the address to allow representing 2^22 cels (4,194,304 cells)

> In computing, a word is the natural unit of data used by a particular processor design. A word is a fixed-sized piece of data handled as a unit by the instruction set or the hardware of the processor.
> (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word)

Using this principle imagine a memory with a word that uses 2 bits only, and it is capable of storing 4 words:

```
XX|YY|WW|ZZ
```

Each word in this memory is represented by a number that tells to computer it's position.

```
XX is 0
YY is 1
WW is 2
ZZ is 3
```

The smallest binary number length that can represent 3 is a 2 bit binary length right? Now apply the same example to a largest memory. Doesn't matters if the word size is 16 bits or 2 bits. Only the length of words matters

Comment: is 22 bits the size of the whole chip? or each line of address because in the question step it says each cell has 16 bits?

Comment: @mathswhizz you are being asked, how many bits you need to store the *binary representation* of the *number of* distinct addressable elements of your memory. The size of each addressable element plays no role, only how many there are. You have 4194304 addressable elements. Convert that number minus one to binary and count how many ones and zeros that is.

Comment: Exactly. When the cell starting position is always multiple of 16 bits. You need to store only the starting position, then multiply by 16 to get the exact position in memory.

Comment: please can you show me a picture diagram of what you mean? @EliasSoares

Comment: See the edited answer

Comment: thanks, how would i answer this question: Assume a 2^20 byte memory. What are the lowest and highest addresses if memory is byte-addressable? How can I answer this if i don't know the word size? @EliasSoares

Comment: The memody is byte addressable, so the word size is one byte.

Comment: each cell is 1 byte which is 8 bits, but how many of these bytes are in a row/address line? @EliasSoares

Comment: That is strictly an implementation detail of the memory chips themselves, and has no relevance to this discussion.  Memory chips differ, but that doesn't matter to the CPU.